# WebAssembly: is there a way to debug/inspect the stack?

Tags: stack, webassembly

Is it possible to inspect the stack while a function is running, or after it trapped? I know this can be achieved by running custom interpreters, but I wonder if this is possible in the default browser environment.

Comment: You can look at the local variables, call stack, set breakpoint in the chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The debugging tools in both Chrome and FireFox allow you to breakpoint wasm modules. They also allow you to inspect their contents by rendering the binary modules in the WebAssembly text format.

When the code is halted via a breakpoint you can see the call stack, local variables etc ...

Comment: Is it possible to access these debugging tools via Javascript?

Comment: Yes it is. Chrome has a remote debugging protocol that allows you to connect to the debugger over the network. This is how you can debug node and chrome from within electron (which is written in JavaScript)